# App Deployment target ignored when uploaded for review

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment, target

I just uploaded my first app for review with iTunesConnect.
I choose the deployment target 3.1.2 and BaseSDK 4.3.
The problem is that in iTunes connect I get this text:

"The binary uploaded for the latest version of this app indicates that iOS 4.3 or later is required. Apps that require iOS 4.3 or later will not be available to Verizon iPhone users. If this app could be compatible with earlier iOS versions, you may want to reject the binary and upload a new one that indicates the earliest compatible iOS."

Why do they ignore my deployment target?
Hope you can help me!

Yours,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places to change the deployment target in Xcode. One is in the Project Info, Info section, Deployment Target field. The other is in the Target Summary, iOS Application Target, Deployment Target field. They should match.

Comment: Ah thank you! The first one was wrong.. How can I reject the binary now and re-up it?

Comment: Forget about it, I'm just reuploading :) You really made my day :)

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, you may not know that it's customary and appreciated when you accept an answer that works for you by clicking the large checkmark next to the answer and mark it as useful. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: :) Okay, didn't know that. I just checked your working answer ;)